# mysql: immediate drop a procedure after it has been called

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can't drop procedure after it has been called.

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'drop procedure if exists some_procedure' at line 2

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS some_procedure;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure() 
BEGIN
   /* Some cool stuff */
END $$

DELIMITER ';'
CALL some_procedure();

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS some_procedure;
```

Comment: why do you want to drop the procedure immediately?

Comment: Actually I do not need it anymore, I have written some query which I need to execute only once, I don't need to keep it in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `DELIMITER ';'` to `DELIMITER ;`

This is from 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Also, it would be heplful to provide your mysql version number